# Inconsistent behavior concerning "Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference"

Tags: perl, perl5.16

Why does the following code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
no warnings 'uninitialized';

use Data::Dumper;

my $user;
my @data = @{$user->{ENTERPRISE}}; # Error on this line
print Dumper($user), qq{Done!\n};
```

Throw the error "`Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference`", while the following code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
no warnings 'uninitialized';

use Data::Dumper;

my $user;
foreach my $enterprise(@{$user->{ENTERPRISES}}) {
    print qq{Enterprise:}, $enterprise;
}
print Dumper($user), qq{Done!\n};
```

Does not throw anything, but instead returns:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'ENTERPRISES' => []
        };
Done!
```

Both have the offending code in them, but only one is throwing the error.

**Possible Answer:** [Perl's autovivification?](http://perlmaven.com/autovivification)

Am I on the right track here? Thanks for your input.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? The fact that you have turned off warnings to do it should be a really good warning bell that it's not a good idea.

Comment: I am just trying to figure out what Perl is doing to throw the error in one place and not in another for the same bit of code. The first code block is from older code that throws the error and has to be fixed, while the second code block is newer code that I am worried will also need the fix but I guess doesn't as it is not throwing the error I saw in the past.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, what happened in the second case is called autovivification, and it only happened in the second case because autovivification only happens for lvalues<sup>[1]</sup>.

So

```
@{ $x } = $y;
```

means

```
@{ $x //= [] } = $y;
```

but

```
$y = @{ $x };
```

doesn't mean

```
$y = @{ $x //= [] };
```

Keep in mind that foreach aliases its loop variable to each element of the list over which it iterates, so those elements are evaluated as lvalues.

Autovivification is documented in [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html), and you can control autovivification through the [autovivification](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?autovivification) pragma.

---

1. If the final deferencing is followed by an indexing (e.g. `->[]` or `->{}`), the reference expression itself is evaluated as an lvalue even if the indexed whole isn't. That means that `$y = $x->[0];` and `$y = ${ $x }[0];` can autovivify `$x` even if `$y = @{ $x };` won't.

Comment: This is very informative. Your last point on how foreach works by aliasing the looping variable causing us to be in a lvalue situation really clears things up. Is the lvalue/rvalue distinction documented somewhere officially?

Comment: @Morrowind789 It's mentioned briefly in [`perldoc perlref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References) in point #3 under "Using References". Also under the definition of autovivification in [perlglossary](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlglossary.html#autovivification).

Comment: The documentation for autovivication (in [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)) does: "This is one of the cases we mentioned earlier in which references could spring into existence when in an lvalue context. [...] This process is called autovivification."

Comment: Also, you can prevent this behavior by adding `no autovivification qw(store)` to your script.

Comment: "it only happened in the second case because it only happens for lvalues." It happens for rvalues, too, but is disallowed by `strict 'refs'`, correct? `perl -E'$a = $b->{c}; say ref($b)'`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, Nothing to do with strict, but my answer wasn't completely correct. (My example was completely wrong.) Fixed.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize `$y = @$x;` doesn't autovivify `$x`. I was confused about strict; the code in my last comment works find under strict.

Comment: Somewhat tangential, but I wonder why `$y = @$x;` throws an exception under strict refs...is it because `undef` is not a hard reference and everything that's not a hard reference is treated as a symbolic reference?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, Gets treated as `@{""}`? Don't know.